# Sqlite sql statement with join, on, and where

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: refs and content

I want to select rows from refs where one column named bi=0.

Then I want to join the refs table and content table when refs.topic_id = content.topic_id

Below is what I tried but is an error because of a join, where, and on statement all together.

```
SELECT refs.topic_id,bi,ci,fvi,tvi
FROM refs
WHERE bi= “0”
JOIN content 
ON refs.topic_id = content.topic_id
ORDER BY bi;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT refs.topic_id,bi,ci,fvi,tvi
FROM refs
JOIN content 
ON refs.topic_id = content.topic_id
WHERE bi= “0”
ORDER BY bi;
```

Answer (score 0):

The join clause must follow directly the from clause.